# duvida na criação de dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou com uma duvida na criação de um dataframe como exemplo

```
dicionario = {'pais': 'brasil', 'capital': 'brasilia', 'clima': 'tropical'}

pd.DataFrame(dicionario)
```

volta erro de index

mas se coloca algum valor em lista

```
dicionario = {'pais': ['brasil'], 'capital': 'brasilia', 'clima': 'tropical'}

pd.DataFrame(dicionario)
```

Volta um pandas dataframe perfeito com index e colunas

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples

use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dicionario])
```

Entretanto, isso é porque tem apenas uma linha. Normalmente você criaria o DataFrame conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> dicionario = {'pais': ['brasil', 'argentina', 'australia'],
                  'capital': ['brasilia', 'buenos aires', 'canberra'],
                  'clima': ['tropical', 'temperado', 'tropical']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dicionario)
>>> df
        pais       capital      clima
0     brasil      brasilia   tropical
1  argentina  buenos aires  temperado
2  australia      canberra   tropical
>>>
```

Espero que ajude